# Necessity to verify if input is not empty string in laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

Is it necessary to verify if input has type `string` and it is not empty in Laravel's validator?

Example:

```
$v = Validator::make(['myinput' => $request->input('myinput')], ['myinput' => 'integer|min:1']);
if (!$v->fails()) {
    $someModel->integer_field = $request->input('myinput');
}
```

Field is not required, and if user supplies this POST request

```
'field' => ''
```

Then Mysql complains about empty string that can not be assigned to integer field.

Also if I provide, for example, empty array as input

```
'field' => []
```

Then it fails too.

So my question is: how to write robust validators for NOT required fields (e.g., if field is present, then it must be:

```
1. For integers: 1,2,3,4,... (+ null value if column is nullable),

so any other supplied value will not pass

(like boolean true which can be converted to 1 automatically but should not)

)

2. For string: '', 'example', ... (+ null value if column is nullable)
```

Here is example https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10747

But `sometimes|required|string` still passes for empty array...

Comment: I thing this thing should not be done in validator (validator should just validate user inputs), but with mutators in models.

Comment: But why? This is what validator is created for.

Comment: I dont think so (maybe i am wrong), but you with validator only validate values (not changing them). If they are valid, then you can change them and insert in database. And e.g. if you want from user non required number, and he dont pass any number, from request you get "" (empty string), and that is correct, becaouse you wanted number or nothing, and empty string is nothing. And now is on you to conwert this "nothing" to something you need.

Comment: @Vitaliy use `$request->input('myinput', $defaultMyInputValue)` for not `required` fields.

Comment: i think after validation is the awnser: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#after-validation-hook